# A good trailing plant to hid a used, but ugly table

Tags: plant-recommendations

I have a table in my garden with a couple of shelves in it.  It's pretty unattractive and the stuff on the shelves doesn't look too good either.

Is there a good plant that that would cover this up?

[image: Ugly table]

Comment: Is it under cover? It seems very shady there - if you cleaned both it and the floor underneath, emptied the ashtray, got rid of that bunch of roots lurking on the left, leaving a spoon or whatever it is and the box on the bottom wouldn't look awful anyway.

Comment: No, it's a south facing balcony, so full morning sunshine.  That being said, the sun would be coming from behind so the table itself will block quite a bit of that sun.

Comment: Are you asking for something you could stand on the table and have it grow over the table, trailing downwards?

Comment: Aye, that's what I'm thinking of.  Something to hides the contents but hardy enough to withstand wind, rain etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, just checked where you are, explains the Banksy ref...

Well, it does get cold there sometimes, I know, so I suggest you use a 7 inch deep trough to sit on top, two if you like, because the soil is then less likely to freeze in a cold winter because there's more of it. Ivy is an obvious contender - one or two of the Hedera helix varieties, whichever ones you fancy or like the look of (Gold Child, Goldheart, Yellow Ripple, Kolibri, Minor Marmorata) but if you do use ivy, just plant that and nothing else in one planter, even if you use two different ones - the roots will take over from anything else you might put in it anyway. Evergreen of course, so year round cover.

The other one I'd recommend is Convulvulus sabatius - without support, it trails downwards for quite a distance, easily a couple of feet. It disappears in the winter, often sold described as an annual trailer for baskets, but it is actually perennial - if the winter isn't bitterly cold, it'll likely survive for some years till its caught by cold. If you do decide to mix ivy with this plant, then take the ivy out every year, pull it apart at the roots, and replant a section or two, bin the rest.

If you just want summer stuff, trailing nasturtiums (Tropaeoleum) will work, but don't start flowering till mid/late June, or the Canary creeper (Tropaeoleum peregrinum) is easily grown from seed in spring.

I am, though, somewhat curious as to how you'll get at anything stored on the other shelves of the table once plants have grown over...

Comment: Thanks Bamboo.  Banksy isn't a reference, just my name (an (un)fortunate one in Bristol)).  I plan on getting to the stuff on the shelves with a clever combination of pruning and brute force, I guess ivy will be more resilient to this than others.  (I'm only thinking that because I think of ivy as pretty much indestructible, without any other real evidence).

Comment: _On a totally separate note:_ Just noticed that [identification] is at the top of your tag list on your profile.  Are you any good at identifying chilli plants?

Comment: Nope - veggies not my thing I'm afraid! Didn't know I had that tag on my list, news to me, I never look. I've added some variety names for Hedera Helix, but there are loads more... just make sure they're H. helix something rather than Hedera colchica or any others. I just came back from Bristol 2 weeks ago after visiting..